# Why external CSS is not working with the HTML?

Tags: html, css

I'm new to Web Development, so I need some help regarding my code. I have validated this code online and is error free, but why the CSS attributes such as `background-color` etc. are not been applied in the HTML?

Also, I would really appreciate if some could comment on my HTML coding style. Is it poor?

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <title>JavaJam Coffee House</title>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="javajam.css">
    </head>
    <body>
        <header>
            <h1>JavaJam Coffee House</h1>
        </header>
        <nav>
            <b><a href="index.html">Home</a> &nbsp; <a href="menu.html">Menu</a></b>
        </nav>
        <main>
            <h2>Relax at JavaJam</h2>
            <ul>
                <li>Specialty Coffee and Tea</li>
                <li>Bagels, Muffins, and Organic Snacks</li>
                <li>Music and Poetry Readings</li>
                <li>Open Mic Night</li>
            </ul>
            <div>
              54321 Route 42<br />
              Ellison Bay, WI 54210<br />
              888-555-5555<br /><br />
            </div>
        </main>
        <footer>
            <small><i>Copyright &copy; 2016 JavaJam Coffee House<br />
            <a href="mailto:abc.xyz.com">abc.xyz.com</a></i></small>
        </footer>
    </body>
</html>
```

The CSS file `javajam.css` is:

```
body {
 background-color: #ffffcc;
 color: red;
 font-family: Verdana, Arial, sans-serif;
}
```

Comment: `head` cannot be styled, I'm pretty sure you want to set that on `body`.

Comment: Yeah! @Pangloss, you are right, I actually wrote that by mistake. But, it doesn't work with body as well.

Comment: @MaxZoom, in the same folder with HTML file.

Comment: The code itself is fine. https://jsfiddle.net/ms1u42uu/. Did you check the browser console for errors?

Comment: @j08691, I know little about it, I think we check it by right clicking and then click on "Inspect in Google Chrome", but there is no errors showing.

Comment: i run your code and its working perfectly on my browser.

Comment: Open the developer tools and go to the console tab, then reload your page. Any messages?

Comment: @j08691, no error at all.

Comment: Strange, try `href="./javajam.css"` Also try to change the HTML text i.e `<title>JavaJamy` and see if it is displayed in the browser. I think you may have duplicated file

Comment: @MaxZoom, it worked :D yahooo! Thank you so much all of you! You may post the answer and I can accept your answer if you like.

Comment: Please note that your other question, "Is it poor?", is off topic for this site. Opinion based questions that have no correct answers are not a good fit. That said, it's fine. No errors according to the W3C validator, which is more than can be said about most actual websites. The indentation is OK too. So, no errors or warnings!

Comment: That only leaves the malformed mailto link. And the `<b>` and the `<i>`. And the two `<br/>`s in a row, as well as the `&nbsp;` as a separator. And the totally unnecessary `<header>` (you could salvage that by putting the <nav> inside it though). And your failed attempt at polyglot markup.

Answer (score -1):

Try putting your `<link>` into the `<body>`. 
For me, I had two `<link>` and they just bugged up each other.
CSS is most likely to work when it is placed in `<body>`.